# How to install "privilege" app using private firefox marketplace(public test server)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-os

I create a firefox marketplace(public test server) using zamboni

http://zamboni.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/install-zamboni/installation.html

and connect to my marketplace url in firefox phone,
so Install app to my app.

**part of the manifest.webapp**

```
"type": "privileged",
"permissions" : {
    "systemXHR": {
        "description" : ""
    },
    "contacts": {
        "access": "readwrite",
        "description" : ""
    },
```

but firefox phone print out log (below)

```
Content JS INFO at app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/app_install_manager.js:198 in ai_handleDownloadError: downloadError event, error code is INVALID_SECURITY_LEVEL
```

1. How can I install "privilege" type app using my marketplace(public test server).

(Note that Success install using "type": "web")

1. Do I need a certified marketplace?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Privileged apps may be distributed through the Firefox Marketplace only.
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps)